# Customized InfoPath form

Tags: infopath

I have a customized InfoPath form that I want to use as a Library. So I created a new Library, set the `Allow management of content types` to YES then selected the custom template. Now when I add a new Item is opens the form but when I fill the form and save it, It does not appear in the item list. How do I fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to setup your submit data connection in InfoPath.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Submit-and-save-form-data-ae82ee07-8acb-4636-8a98-0a7bf664a998?ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US

See the section on how to add a data connection and then for SharePoint library or list.

Answer (score 0):

You should publish the form to the library

1. Open the working copy of the form template in design mode.
2. On the File menu, click Publish.
3. In the Publishing Wizard, click To a SharePoint server with or without InfoPath Forms Services, and then click Next.
4. In the Enter the location of your SharePoint or InfoPath Forms Services site box, type the location of the SharePoint site that contains the new document library that you want to move your form template to, and then click Next.
5. On the next page of the wizard, click Document Library, and then click Next.
6. Click Create a new document library, and then click Next.
   On the next page of the wizard, type a name and description for the new document library, and then click Next.
7. Choose the fields in the form template that you want to appear as columns in the default view of the document library.
8. Click Next.
   9.On the next page of the wizard, verify that the information shown is correct, and then click Publish.
9. To open the document library and test the process for filling out a form that is based on this form template, select the Open this document library check box, and then click Close.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/infopath-help/move-a-published-form-template-to-a-new-sharepoint-library-HP010102446.aspx

Comment: Infopath form that I have is a customized form and it was approved as a template by the admin. Unlink regualer forms, customized form does not create a library. Library has to be created manually and then template has to be changed to the customized form template and that is what I did. When I click on add new items it brings the correct form but once I fill the form and save it, that saved form does not appear in the list.